# ListView and Form on the same view, using the form to filter the results

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and I've been trying to make so small app after reading the tutorial but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

What I'm trying to do is listing all the database entries of a model called project using a ListView with a form below it (using the same view) that the user can use to filter the entries to be shown by means of submitting data in text fields.

I managed to make that work, and it looks like this:

[image: App]

However, once the user clicks the "Filter results" button providing some filtering pattern on the textfields (let's say, filter by name = "PROJECT3", leaving the other fields blank), instead of rendering a page with the filtered data and the form below it, which is my intention, it just returns a white page.

Can anyone please explain me what is wrong with my code?

Here are the relevant parts:

forms.py

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    pjt_name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'20'}))
    pjt_status = forms.CharField(label='Status', max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'20'}) )
    pjt_priority = forms.CharField(label='Priority', max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'20'}))
    pjt_internal_sponsor = forms.CharField(label='Int Sponsor', max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'20'}))
    pjt_external_sponsor = forms.CharField(label='Ext Sponsor', max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'20'}))
```

views.py

```
from App.models import Project
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext
from App.forms import FilterForm

class ProjectListView(ListView):

    context_object_name = 'project_list'
    template_name='App/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(ProjectListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            if 'filter_form' not in context:
                    context['filter_form'] = FilterForm()
            return context

    def get_queryset(self):
            form = FilterForm(self.request.GET)
            if form.is_valid():
                    name = form.cleaned_data['pjt_name']
                    i_sp = form.cleaned_data['pjt_internal_sponsor']
                    e_sp = form.cleaned_data['pjt_external_sponsor']
                    status = form.cleaned_data['pjt_status']
                    pri = form.cleaned_data['pjt_priority']
                    return send_filtered_results(name, i_sp, e_sp, status, pri)
            else:
                    return Project.objects.order_by('-project_creation_date')[:5]

    def send_filtered_results(name, i_sp, e_sp, status, pri):
            return  Project.objects.filter(project_name__in=name,internal_sponsor_name__in=i_sp, external_sponsor_name__in=e_sp, project_status__in=status, project_priority__in=pri).exclude(alias__isnull=True).exclude(alias__exact='')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from App.views import ProjectListView
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from App.models import Project, Task

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',
            ProjectListView.as_view())
```

Comment: Completely white? What's the status code? What's your server say? Errors? Are you in debug mode?

Comment: Hi, yes I'm in debug mode. No errors. First I access index.html, that is the page show in the image and runserver returns [23/Jan/2015 00:21:03] "GET /App/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2607
 Then I put something into the testfields and press the button. After doing that I get a white page and runserver returns [23/Jan/2015 00:21:09] "POST /App/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in your response/status code:

> After doing that I get a white page and runserver returns [23/Jan/2015 00:21:09] "POST /App/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

You're POSTing to a view that has no POST handler. **You should** be getting an error saying so, but the 405 means method not allowed.

Add a `post` method to your `CBV`. Django class based views map request method to functions, so a `GET` is handled via `CBV.get`, `POST` via `CBV.post`

For demonstration purposes, add:

```
# essentially, mirror get behavior exactly on POST
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
```

And change your form handler to pull from `request.POST` not `request.GET`.

```
        form = FilterForm(self.request.POST)
```

I suggest you start using `print()`s or `log` to start seeing what's happening. `request.GET` should be empty, as.. you're not using GET parameters. That data will be in `request.POST`.

Comment: Thanks !! This was the root cause of the problem. I finally got the app working after changing that and other few things.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is messy and your `Project.objects.filter(...)` is far to aggressive. It just doesn't return any objects.

Don't use `name__in=name` but `name__contains=name`.

Comment: Hi, I've changed in by contains on all fields but still no luck. But that was wrong too, thanks. In any case, I'm not getting anything, so there must be something else wrong in how I return the httpresponse. It is not redirecting correctly after I do the POST request.

Comment: This is useful code advice but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Ah, you're using POST! GET and POST are typically used for different purposes. GET is suitable for things like a web search form, because the URLs that represent a GET request can easily be bookmarked, shared, or resubmitted. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#get-and-post So, in your case, change the form to use GET. `<form ... method='get'>`.